# Joining Two Table in SQL

Tags: sql

Tbl1:

```
CID   Detail
1     d1
2     d2
3     d3
```

Tbl2:

```
ID     CID    FileType
1      1      1
2      1      2
3      2      2
```

Result required: all From Table1, null if FileType is null or <> 1

```
CID   Detail  FileType
1     d1      1
2     d2      null
3     d3      null
```

Comment: Try to format the sample data, and result, in proper columns. Also add a <tag> for the dbms product you're using.

Comment: Please improve your format we cant read properly your sample data .

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Your sample data does not contain a CID = 2 for table 2, so why does the expected result contain `cid = 2, detail = d2`?

Comment: Still not very clear what you are trying to do. Given that your sample data in tbl2 has has filetype 1 and 2 for cid 1 I think that you want "Give me everything in table1 and '1' for filetype if any matching row in tbl2 exists with filetype=1 otherwise null' --> In that case you are not joining tables but should look into subselects.

Comment: It means file type 1 is not added for CID=2 & And not any filetype added for CID=3

Comment: Eddy- Can you give SubSelect Sql for it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a 1-1 assignment.  Something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.FileType
from tbl1 t1 left join
     (select tbl2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cid order by id) as seqnum
      from tbl2
     ) t2
     on t2.cid = t1.cid and t2.seqnum = 1 and
        t2.FileType = 1;
```

Comment: CASE WHEN EXISTS  (SELECT     Table2.SID FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.sid = Table2.sid AND Table2.FileType = '1') THEN  (SELECT     Table2.FileType FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.SID = Table2.SID AND Table2.FileType = '1')  ELSE NULL END AS YM

Comment: You are almost there, But Need NULL when FileType is Missing against SID(CID). Thanks for all the support and very quick response.

Comment: @SamirShah . . . This should return all rows in `tbl1`.  If there is no match in `tbl2`, then the corresponding value will be `NULL` in the query.